# How do I add a dependency to Buildout?

Tags: python, buildout

I'm quite new to Buildout, but I just got my first Django application building in it thanks to the nice tutorial [here](http://jacobian.org/writing/django-apps-with-buildout/). I'm used to using Maven, so how do I "add a dependency" so Buildout will download it and include it in the build? Here's my `buildout.cfg` file:

```
[buildout]
parts = python django
develop = .
eggs = my-project
versions = versions

[versions]
django = 1.3

[python]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
interpreter = python
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}

[django]
recipe = djangorecipe
project = my-project
projectegg = my-project
settings = settings
test = my-project
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
```

What do I need to change here to add a dependency to `south`, version 0.7.3 (or the latest)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the name of the required dependency to `setup.py`'s `install_requires` array:

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires = ['setuptools', 'south'],
    ...
)
```

Comment: Exactly correct! Which is to say, TK Kocheran, that the dependency you are adding is, properly speaking, a dependency of your Django application, not of your buildout; thus why it's over in a file that belongs to the Django app.

Comment: The `setup.py` exclusively belongs to Django? I'm talking about [this](http://pastebin.com/3hdKCsbt) file.

Comment: A `setup.py` file belongs to a Python package — which, in your case, happens to be a Django application — and says “here is a list of the things that this package needs.”  Which in the case of your particular Python package (“Django application”) includes south.  So after adding `'south'` to the `install_requires` you should be able to re-run buildout and see it install South.

Comment: Ok, gotcha, was a bit confused there :)